# How to know if application insights telemetry client is functional?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

This code execute without any errors, but obviously will not log anything in ApplicationInsights. The `foobar` key is not valid.

```
 var client = new TelemetryClient
 {
    Context = { InstrumentationKey = "foobar" }
 };

 client.TrackEvent(telemetryEvent);
```

I understand that it may be a good thing. I dont want my application to crash because AppInsights is not avalaible. But it would be nice to know somehow that it is not reachable, so I can do something else instead.

Possible errors that I think could append :

- The api is not reachable
- The event is malformed
- the api key is invalid
- etc.

Some of these may be transcient (api temporary not available), but others may not (invalid api key).

Is there any way I could "test" the client to react to these cases?

Something like :

```
if (!client.IsAppInsightReachable)
{
  //Send an email to someone so he can check if everything is OK
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to do it, you probably could, but it might be a lot of work re-inventing the wheel.

you'd have to do a lot of the work yourself, implementing or wrapping things like [`ITelemetryChannel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.applicationinsights.channel.aspx)  to do what you want.

Much of the source for the [various application insights sdks are up on github](https://github.com/Microsoft?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=applicationinsights):

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get some understanding on how the telemetry client is doing, see my own question, where I describe how I managed to detect connection problems to Application Insights:

[Detecting whether or not (and why) Application Insights can send telemetry data to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34431388/34838)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use Fiddler as a proxy to see whether events are being sent from the SDK. **[This blog](http://www.apmtips.com/blog/2014/12/19/proxy-application-insights-events/)** describes how this can be done.

Comment: I wanted _code_ to detec if it is working, so I can, say, send an email to someone if it is not working over a certain period of time. I will rephrase my question...