# Detecting whether or not (and why) Application Insights can send telemetry data to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm developing a Windows Desktop application and have successfully linked the Application Insights Core assemblies. I'm using `TrackTrace`, `TrackEvent`, etc. to send custom telemetry.

On some workstations telemetry is successfully sent to the Azure portal, and on some others it is not, although calls to `TrackTrace`, `Flush`, etc. succeed (or at least return without throwing an exception. `TelemetryClient.IsEnabled()` returns true. Both workstations use an `InMemoryChannel`, with the same endpoint                 `https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track` and the sending interval is 30 seconds.

Is there an API function I can call in my application to get the connection status of the TelemetryClient? Something that would tell me that the client is successfully connected, or that it encountered error **x** while trying, and still has **y** telemetry packets waiting to be sent.

I'm not looking for a checklist like *reinstall the NuGet package* (I did...), *Make sure your firewall allows traffic to port xxx* (it does...) or *try to install kb...871* (I did that too...). What I'd like is a status report that I can log somewhere on the client workstation while my application runs, at least acknowledging in the status bar (Yes I know status bars are so old fashioned these days) that there is a problem.

**First update - Getting the queue size**

First victory, I was able to get the queue size. I wanted to do that without creating my own channel implementation (yet). This however is of little help to detect outages, because the queue will drain even if the transmitter is unable to transmit the telemetry items (it will just discard them) - more on this later. At least you know the transmitter thread is running...

```
private ITelemetryChannel _TelemetryChannel;
private InMemoryChannel _InMemoryChannel;
private object _TelemetryBuffer;
private object _BufferLock;
private object _InMemoryTransmitter;

_TelemetryChannel = TelemetryConfiguration.Active?.TelemetryChannel;
if (_TelemetryChannel != null && _TelemetryChannel is InMemoryChannel)
{
  _InMemoryChannel = (InMemoryChannel)_TelemetryChannel;
  _TelemetryBuffer = GetInstanceField (_InMemoryChannel, "buffer");
  _BufferLock = GetInstanceField (_TelemetryBuffer, "lockObj");
  _InMemoryTransmitter = GetInstanceField (_InMemoryChannel, "transmitter");
}

public int GetTelemetryQueueSize ()
{
    if (_BufferLock != null)
    {
        lock (_BufferLock)
        {
            object l = GetInstanceField (_TelemetryBuffer, "items");
            if (l is List<ITelemetry>)
            {
                return ((List<ITelemetry>)l).Count;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You also need an utility function to use reflection to access the private fields of the objects (the buffer and transmitter are `internal sealed`...) I made these as error resistant as possible, they could be more concise.

```
private static object GetInstanceField (Type type, object instance, string fieldName)
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    try
    {
        BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static;
        FieldInfo field = type.GetField (fieldName, bindFlags);
        return field.GetValue (instance);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}

private static object GetInstanceField (object instance, string fieldName)
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return GetInstanceField (instance.GetType (), instance, fieldName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I managed to make it work... There is no API to do it, so I created a new custom Telemetry Channel that actually reports the errors, and that I can rely on.

Edit: it appears from comments that `ReliableTelemetryChannel` is not an appropriate name for this class. It should be named `ProbingTelemetryChannel`. Thanks.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation;

namespace Streambolics.Telemetry
{
  public class ReliableTelemetryChannel : ITelemetryChannel
  {
    private Uri _EndpointAddress;
    private int _Attempts, _Successes, _Failures;
    private Exception _LastFailure;
    private DateTime _LastFailureTime;

    public ReliableTelemetryChannel ()
    {
      EndpointAddress = TelemetryConfiguration.Active?.TelemetryChannel?.EndpointAddress;
    }

    public bool? DeveloperMode {
        get { return true; }
        set { }
    }

    public string EndpointAddress {
        get { return _EndpointAddress?.ToString (); }
        set {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (value))
                _EndpointAddress = null;
            else
                _EndpointAddress = new Uri (value);
        }
    }

    public void Flush () { }

    public void Send (ITelemetry item)
    {
      _Attempts++;

      try
      {
        item.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        byte[] data = JsonSerializer.Serialize (new ITelemetry[] { item });
        var transmission = new Transmission (_EndpointAddress, data, "application/x-json-stream", JsonSerializer.CompressionType);
        transmission.SendAsync ().GetAwaiter ().GetResult ();
        _Successes++;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          _Failures++;
          _LastFailure = ex;
          _LastFailureTime = DateTime.Now;
      }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose (bool disposing) { }
    public void Dispose ()
    { Dispose (true); }
  }
}
```

Now it's just a matter of creating the channel and a client on that channel:

```
var _ReliableChannel = new ReliableTelemetryChannel ();
var _ReliableConfiguration = new TelemetryConfiguration ();
_ReliableConfiguration.TelemetryChannel = _ReliableChannel;
var _ReliableClient = new TelemetryClient (_ReliableConfiguration);
_ReliableClient.InstrumentationKey = "...";
```

Now I just regularly send a probe, and query the channel for error statistics:

```
_ReliableClient.TrackEvent ("TelemetryProbe");
GlobalLog.Log ("Probe attempts {0} Last Error {1}", _ReliableChannel.Attempts, _ReliableChannel.LastFailure);
```

It doesn't solve the global problem of detecting whether the active configuration works (the one that I use to send regular telemetry, with buffering etc.), but at least I can safely assume that if my Reliable channel is working, the regular one is working too.

Comment: ApplicationInsights uses ETW to log failures. You can subscribe to it and repost to your log. Or use perfview for one time investigations. More on that here: http://sergeysharp.com/blog/2015/04/16/diagnostic-of-applicationinsights-sdk/

Comment: Indeed (i tried that too). Unfortunately the logging of errors is free form (it uses CoreEventSource.Log.LogVerbose to report errors) and needs re-parsing (and finger crossing, hoping the surrounding text shall never be localized) to detect what went wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Note: the persistence channel was discontinued shortly after I wrote this.

You got it to work, but all you did was creating a Persistence Channel that already exist.

You should've done the following:

```
  using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
  using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
  ...

  // Set up 
  TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "YOUR INSTRUMENTATION KEY";

  TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel = new PersistenceChannel();
```

On Application Exit, make sure you call the

```
telemetryClient.Flush()
```

to flush the telemetry data to the channel.

What this does is write your telemetry data to disk and periodically flush the data to the Azure cloud. This is great for intermittent internet connectivity and also for cases where the app closes before all data could be sent.

On startup, you can add a tiny sleep delay to ensure that the data from a previous session is sent to the cloud.

The code samples has been taken from the [Application Insights Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-desktop/) where more detail can be found.

Comment: Hi. While I value your input, it does not entirely answer my question, which was to know **whether** and **why** telemetry data was (not) sent. I specifically explained in my post that I did not want a list of things to try in order to make it work, I wanted a way to detect at runtime that it is not working (btw this also excludes "enable logging" as a valid answer)... FYI telemetry was not sent because the application was running on a Windows XP SP1 workstation, and the SSL root certificates were stale. Flushing and storing to disk would not help in that case...

Comment: Ok, valid point. To a certain extent my answer would be valid to other users that dont require your detailed ProbingChannel. In most cases a Persistent channel should suffice, although clearly not in you instance. It does make for interesting reading...

Comment: Yes indeed, most use scenarios for telemetry is fire and forget. I will definitely use a persistent channel for regular telemetry (the probing channel is there only to send a probe every 15 minutes or so) and I'll see if I can extract queue sizes etc from it by peeking into private fields (seems difficult though, the transmitter fires multiple Sender threads that come and go, the info might be highly volatile)

Comment: The PersistenceChannel stopped existing about a month after this answer was written.